# replace values of a row with values from another row

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na, rowwise

```
wave <-c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2)

id   <-c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)

var1 <-c(6.341464, 13.206567, NA, 5.272296,2.746650, NA, 1.684472,1.874200, 15.861959, 3.938463)

var2 <-c(6.341464, 13.206567, NA, 5.272296,2.746650, NA, 1.684472,1.874200, 15.861959, 3.938463)

var3 <-c(6.341464, 13.206567, NA, 5.272296,2.746650, NA, 1.684472,1.874200, 15.861959, 3.938463)


df<- data.frame(wave,id,var1,var2,var3)
```

## Output:df

[image]

**How can I replace NA's in wave 3 with values from wave 2?**
**it should copy all the values from second wave (NA too)**

I tried for loop but without success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option with Base R, could be using `which` to find the row indexes of wave 3 and use -1 index to replace the values like this:

```r
df[which(wave == '3'),c("var1","var2","var3")] = df[which(wave == '3')-1,c("var1","var2","var3")]
df
#>    wave id      var1      var2      var3
#> 1     1  1  6.341464  6.341464  6.341464
#> 2     2  2 13.206567 13.206567        NA
#> 3     3  3 13.206567 13.206567        NA
#> 4     1  4  5.272296  5.272296  5.272296
#> 5     2  5  2.746650  2.746650  2.746650
#> 6     3  6  2.746650  2.746650  2.746650
#> 7     1  7  1.684472  1.684472  1.684472
#> 8     2  8  1.874200  1.874200  1.874200
#> 9     1  9 15.861959 15.861959 15.861959
#> 10    2 10  3.938463  3.938463  3.938463
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Another option from @TarJae, thanks!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  filter(wave == 2 | wave == 3) %>%    
  fill(var1:var3, .direction = "down") %>%    
  bind_rows(df) %>%    
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%    
  arrange(id)
#>    wave id      var1      var2      var3
#> 1     1  1  6.341464  6.341464  6.341464
#> 2     2  2 13.206567 13.206567        NA
#> 3     3  3 13.206567 13.206567        NA
#> 4     1  4  5.272296  5.272296  5.272296
#> 5     2  5  2.746650  2.746650  2.746650
#> 6     3  6  2.746650  2.746650  2.746650
#> 7     1  7  1.684472  1.684472  1.684472
#> 8     2  8  1.874200  1.874200  1.874200
#> 9     1  9 15.861959 15.861959 15.861959
#> 10    2 10  3.938463  3.938463  3.938463
```

---

**Old answer, different data OP**

You could use `fill` with a down direction like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  fill(var1:var3, .direction = 'down')
#>    wave id      var1      var2      var3
#> 1     1  1  6.341464  6.341464  6.341464
#> 2     2  2 13.206567 13.206567 13.206567
#> 3     3  3 13.206567 13.206567 13.206567
#> 4     1  4  5.272296  5.272296  5.272296
#> 5     2  5  2.746650  2.746650  2.746650
#> 6     3  6  2.746650  2.746650  2.746650
#> 7     1  7  1.684472  1.684472  1.684472
#> 8     2  8  1.874200  1.874200  1.874200
#> 9     1  9 15.861959 15.861959 15.861959
#> 10    2 10  3.938463  3.938463  3.938463
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you Quinten! That is the direction I want to. unfortunetly my data was not quit precise above. The way you suggest puts all the values from above row into below one. What I want is, it should put only values from second wave into third. If in var3 in second row value is NA it schoud bring this NA in third wave too. Sorry for my mistake and I'm glad to hear your suggestion again :)

Comment: I updated my quastion and data too above. your contribution was definetly helpfull!

Comment: Try this: `df %>% 
  filter(wave == 2 | wave == 3) %>% 
  fill(var1:var3, .direction = "down") %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(id)`

Comment: @TarJae, that is a great option! You could share that as an answer?

Comment: Hi @Mskhvilidze, I added a different option by using `which` to find the rows with wave 3 and replace them by the previous row using -1 index. Please see edit!

Comment: @Quinten it works like I want on this example data. But I get an following  Error on the main data "Error in which(wave == "3") : object 'wave' not found". I can't explain myself why I get this error.

Comment: @Mskhvilidze, this says that your wave column isn't found. Do you have a different name for the wave column maybe in your main data?

Comment: @Quinten Please feel free to add it to your answer if there is some benefit!

Comment: I had to overwrite your code a bit like this "df[which(df$wave == '3'),c("var1","var2","var3")] = df[which(df$wave == '3')-1,c("var1","var2","var3")]" and now it functions everywhere. Thank you very much for your efforts, it helped me a lot

Comment: @TarJae, Added your option as well, thanks!